# template instantiation check for member existing in class

Tags: c++, class, templates, instantiation, member

I have a group of classes that have one or more members of the type memberA, memberB, memberC. Not all classes have all the members. I want to create a template that will set the members such as

```
template <typename T>
void setAttributes(t & myClass, typeA memA, typeB memB, typeC memC)
{
  myClass.memberA = memA;
  myClass.memberB = memb;
  myClass.memberC = memC;
}
```

Obviously this will fail at compile time when attempting to instantiate a class that is missing one of the members. Is there a #if or something similar that will allow the check to be done for a conditional compile of the form

```
#ifdef myClass.memberA
  myClass.memberA = memA;
#endif
```

I do not have access right now to actually try this or anything similar and I would like to know if there is a valid way of setting it up.

I have seen references to SFINAE ("substitution failure is not an error.") but I am not sure how it would be used in this case. Is the suggestion below correct?

[Substitution failure is not an error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) example would seem to imply that I should create a separate function for each member with a duplicate function without that member.

```
template <typename T>
void setMemberA(T & myClass, typeA memA)
{
  myClass.memberA = memA;
}

template <typenum T>
void setMemberA(T & myClass)
{
  // This is a dummy template to avoid a compilation problem
}
```

Comment: You may want to use SFINAE.

Comment: @user4098326 I have seen references to this but have not been able to extrapolate from the examples given to my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible `set_memberA_if_exists` implementation:

```
namespace details {
    template<class T>
    auto set_memberA_if_exists_impl(T & myClass, typeA memA, int) 
         -> decltype(myClass.memberA = memA, void()) {
        myClass.memberA = memA;
    }

    template<class T>
    void set_memberA_if_exists_impl(T & myClass, typeA memA, long) {}
}

template<class T>
void set_memberA_if_exists(T & myClass, typeA memA) {
     details::set_memberA_if_exists_impl(myClass, memA, 0);
}
```

Explanation:

SFINAE applies only to the signature, not the body, of the function template, so the trick is to encode the check inside the function template signature. This is easy using a C++11 trailing return type - `-> decltype(myClass.memberA = memA, void())`. If the expression `myClass.memberA = memA` would not compile, then it causes a substitution failure and removes the function template from the overload set. So that a call to `set_memberA_if_exists_impl` will still compile in that case, we also provide another do-nothing overload.

We also need a way to distinguish between those two overloads when they are both viable. This is done by introducing a third parameter. The do-something overload's third parameter's type is `int`, while the do-nothing overload's is `long`. By providing `0` (an `int`) as the third argument when we call it, we make sure that the do-something overload is preferred when it is viable.

Comment: very clever, +1. The SFINAE takes places in `decltype`, right? And the `,` is the good old comma operator, which you used only to be able to evaluate the first expression `myClass.memberA = memA`, is this correct?

Comment: @vsoftco Pretty much.